# Strange problem while iterating on a map after erasing in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, erase

I have a tiles map which contains all my tiles. I would like to erase one tile and continue to draw my tiles in same time.

The problem is that after i've erased one tile (like index = 2) the first complete iteration of tiles draw is correct(draw 0,1,3,4,...), but the second make crash because it try to draw all tiles (0,1,2,3,...)

here is my code to erase one tile

```
auto it = tiles.begin();
while(it != tiles.end()){
    if(it->first == i){
        it = tiles.erase(it);
    }
    else
        ++it;
}
```

and here is my code to draw

```
for(auto& itr : tiles){
    if(itr.first == limit)
        break;
    if(itr.first < 10){
        cout<<"draw : "<<itr.first<<"\t"<<itr.second.str()<<endl;
    }
    itr.second.draw(window,dt);
}
```

(limit is to not iterate over the x thousands of tiles)

and here the console output

draw : 0        (0,24)stay
draw : 1        (32,24)stay
draw : 2        (64,24)stay
draw : 3        (96,24)stay
draw : 4        (128,24)stay
draw : 5        (160,24)stay
draw : 6        (192,24)stay
draw : 7        (224,24)stay
draw : 8        (256,24)stay
draw : 9        (288,24)stay

delete 0 :
0       (0,24)stay
1       (32,24)stay

draw : 1        (32,24)stay
draw : 2        (64,24)stay
draw : 3        (96,24)stay
draw : 4        (128,24)stay
draw : 5        (160,24)stay
draw : 6        (192,24)stay
draw : 7        (224,24)stay
draw : 8        (256,24)stay
draw : 9        (288,24)stay

draw : 0        (-1163005939,-1163005939)

Sorry for my english and thank you for your help.

Comment: why not ```tiles.erase(tiles.find(i))``` ?

Comment: There is a bug somewhere in your code. The bug can be anywhere. There's nothing in the shown code to indicate what the bug is; therefore you must show a [mre], otherwise it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com will be able to help you. For more information, see [ask].

Comment: By the sentence **and continue to draw in the same time**, do you mean from another thread? If so, you cannot modify a map from a thread while another thread iterate over it. You have to use a lock (ex. `std::mutex`) if this is want you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

When erase value of iteration, the iteration couldn’t point the next one so the simple way is:

```
  auto it = m.begin();
  while (it != m.end()) 
  {
    if (it->first == 1)
      m.erase(it++); // After return from erase function, it point to next pointer.
    else
      ++it;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's most probable that you do not actually erase the element from the tile map you are then drawing. How do you pass the map to the code which removes tiles? It's possible that you are creating a copy somewhere.

FYI a code like this works, so there is no obvious error with yours. The bug is somewhere outside of the code you have posted.

```
int main() {
  std::map<int, std::string> m = {{0, "A"}, {1, "B"}, {2, "C"}};

  for (auto& t : m) {
    std::cout << t.first << " = " << t.second << std::endl;
  }

  auto it = m.begin();
  while (it != m.end()) {
    if (it->first == 1) {
      it = m.erase(it);
    } else {
      ++it;
    }
  }

  for (auto& t : m) {
    std::cout << t.first << " = " << t.second << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No copy are creating, i've tested copy constructor and operator =. 
Moreover the code inside the main loop (where miner is my player and update take in charge collision,movement and deleting)
      miner.update(time);
      tileMap.printTiles();
      tileMap.draw(window,time,sf::Vector2f(miner.getX(),miner.getY()));
give me in console exactly the same (first iterate ok, second iterate crash)
Another thing to know is that before this bug I was using a vector and everything was working fine. However, for performance problems during the erase I modified the vector to a map <int,Tile>

Comment: Can you post a minimal example with all of the code that causes the issue then? You are obviously not just erasing a tile and drawing it because that would work.